# Restricting GameKit to Bluetooth (alternative: Finding Out Whether GameKit Is Using Bluetooth or WiFi)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, bluetooth, gamekit

### What is the Problem?

I want to communicate between two iDevices (iPhone, iPod, iPad, iPad mini) over Bluetooth. As far as I know, [GameKit](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GameKit/Reference/GameKit_Collection/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008303) is all that Apple offers without using private API. Unfortunately, it's AFAIK not possible to restrict GameKit to Bluetooth because GameKit decides itself whether it connects to the other peer(s) using Bluetooth or a WiFi connection. Worse, I didn't find any way to find out whether an established GameKit connection is using Bluetooth or WiFi.

### What is the Question?

- Preferred: How to restrict GameKit to Bluetooth?
- Alternative 1: How to decide whether a GameKit connection uses Bluetooth, WiFi or anything else?
- Alternative 2: What else could I use to communicate over Bluetooth between two iDevices?

### Restrictions?

- No private API a.k.a. AppStore compatible
- Has to work offline
- Not limited to Bluetooth 4.0 Low Energy

Answer (score -2):

Since iOS 5, Apple released Core Bluetooth Framework. Take a look at that: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreBluetooth/Reference/CoreBluetooth_Framework/_index.html

Comment: I know, but open the link and view the documentation "The CoreBluetooth framework provides access to Bluetooth 4.0 low energy devices." Other iDevices are no "Bluetooth 4.0 low energy devices"

Comment: I get it... in that case, Why don't you use bump API to connect devices? It works well to me!  http://bu.mp/company/api

Comment: Hmm, would be an idea but the solution should work offline :-(

Comment: (added the offline requirement in the question)

Comment: You should add (as a restriction) that you want to use bluetooth in old devices (non Bluetooth 4 devices)